# Round Robin Scheduling - Arrival Time Tie which comes first?

Tags: process, scheduling, round-robin

What happens if there is a tie in the arrival time of two processes in Round Robin Scheduling? Does the order(not stated) matters or their Burst Time is considered?
What will be the difference between the two?

Example: 
p1 AT=0 BT =30

p2 AT = 1 BT = 20

p3 AT = 1 BT = 10

Which process is given CPU time first p2 or p3?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest p2, as the name 2 implied that it was earlier then p3.